# Is it annoying to post a lot of code in my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, code-formatting

I've used StackOverflow for some time, but I'm just starting to ask questions (and even answer a few).

As I read through instructions on how to participate in Stack Overflow, I remember reading that it's helpful to be brief and to the point (I believe that statement was in an article S.O. linked to in their participation instructions).

Is it helpful or not helpful to paste a lot of code in my question, if my program uses multiples files (more than one of which relates to my problem?)

I'm guessing I should supply as much information as necessary to help others understand my question, but I think sometimes posting a lot of code makes posts look unnecessarily bulky.

I think posting a link to GitHub (if using Github) can be helpful, but even then some questions need to be illustrated with code in the post itself.

What guidelines are there about including code?

Comment: Yes, it is annoying. Usually, it just means you didn't put in the effort to create an MCVE, so people are right to be annoyed. Sometimes, it's warranted anyway—but that's rare enough that when it happens, you'll almost certainly want some CYA text explaining _why_ it's warranted. If you do that, some people will get past their annoyance and answer you, and hopefully the others will just TL;DR and move on without downvoting or closing.

Comment: The **relevant**  code has to be in your question itself, not on an external site. If the code is somewhere off-site, and that off-site server is unavailable for some reason (offline, moved, etc.), the question has no value to future readers. Posting a link to GitHub or somewhere else to see your code is not appropriate - the **relevant** code needs to be in your question here. Note that I've emphasized the word **relevant** - this does not mean *code dump of your entire project*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most important guideline is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guideline:

> When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be…
>
> - Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
> - Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem
> - Verifiable - Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

Occasionally, the minimal code to reproduce the problem will still be pretty big. In that case (if you're sure it really is minimal), you don't really have any choice but to post a lot of code. But because that's so rare, and because your question will probably *look* like a thoughtless code dump even though it isn't, I'd suggest including a bit of text explaining why all of it is relevant.

Meanwhile, including a link to a larger project at GitHub is a great idea, if it's relevant. Just make sure that the question stands on its own without that link—that your MCVE really is Complete.