# Questions about localizing a problem

Tags: discussion, scope, minimal-reproducible-example

I see these quite regularly. An OP provides all the means to reproduce the issue, shows the actual result etc. The problem is, the question is actually a request to localize the issue for them.

A recent example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100387/why-is-my-website-messed-up-on-ios

While the environment provided is often reasonably scoped for the OP to expect free help, there are these traits to such questions that appear to contradict the nature of SO:

- While the system is small, it's still too large to fit into the question proper (typically a few full files or an external web page)

  - and it cannot be reduced to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because reducing it *is* the question
- The issue is specific to the system, thus not useful for future readers

  - Sure, the root cause, if it's identified, is very likely to be a recurring problem. But there's nothing in the question that points to it - thus the question is impossible to find by relevant keywords - and even if found, impossible for another reader to relate to their case

---

So:

- Are these questions completely off topic and have to be closed? Or can they be fixed somehow?
- If closed, with which stock reason?
- If fixed, how should we request the OP to fix it?

Comment: Any question asking people to visit the OP's website to determine what's wrong with it is off topic.

Comment: As the phrase "request to localize the issue for them" testifies, related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason/336658#336658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MCVE is required for "debug my code" questions.

There are many discussions that code must be provided inline in the post and possibly accompanied with links to version-controlled or immutable locations to complete/bigger demonstrations, pointing to an actual production site is not an option at all as presumably problem will be gone as soon as solution is found. See [Add an optional field to link to source code repository when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334456/add-an-optional-field-to-link-to-source-code-repository-when-asking-a-question/334462#334462) and [If your MCVE is still somewhat large, is it OK to post a link to github?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294029/if-your-mcve-is-still-somewhat-large-is-it-ok-to-post-a-link-to-github) for example.

Your options:

- "missing MCVE" is usually good close reason with detailed instructions to OP. Separately consider if post deserves downvote due to lack of research/effort to find solution.
- If you believe there is enough information to create MCVE inline in the post and end result will be on-topic - you can do it yourself and edit post with cleaned up sample. Be prepared that creating MCVE in most cases will lead to some typo or well known duplicate. Makes sure you are fine to spend your time that way. This is strictly personal preference option - from site's point of view it would be more practical to move on to better questions. Also note that such edit may remove other reasons OP wanted to ask question and be considered inappropriate. Not really an option if your edits require review. Make sure to add comment to OP to confirm the change.

**Do not answer** question in such state. If you know the answer - either convenience OP to make an edit or at least confirm that it is the problem. Make sure question is updated shortly around time you've provided answer (at most hours).

Comment: _"Be prepared that creating MCVE in most cases will lead to some typo or well known duplicate"_ - that's what I am driving at. The question is basically whether the community currently feels ('cuz [help/mcve] certainly doesn't) the amount of work/knowledge needed to do that is justification enough to tolerate "dirty" problem statements and/or allow this very task to be the topic of a question.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it is personal decision - from the site's point of view downvote/VTC and move to answer existing better question is preferable as time you volunteer is the limited resource here. But if you really like making MCVE an digging through code - you are very welcome to unearth precious gems from such questions. I've updated post to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think the biggest red flag you found was this:

> - While the system is small, it's still too large to fit into the question proper (typically a few full files or an external web page)

This *instantly* makes me think "too broad", since now I have to consider looking at an entire web page or application, and not some reduced, simpler subset.

> Are these questions completely off topic and have to be closed? Or can they be fixed somehow?

They can't be fixed by *us*, as laymen, coming from the outside looking in.  They have to be fixed by the OP, and the only way to ensure that it gets the time it needs to be fixed is to put it on hold/close it.

> If closed, with which stock reason?

Choose the reason that fits with the instance.

- Is the question asking a fairly open-ended question with a lot of code to go along with it?  **Too broad.**
- Is there no clear question being asked?  **Unclear what you're asking.**
- Is the question asking for "best practices" or an otherwise veiled, "What would you do?"  **Opinion-based.**
- Does the question have problems with code but includes neither code, nor problems, nor both?  **Why isn't this code working?**

The OP needs to fix the question and bring it down to a simpler subset for us to look into.  We can't debug an entire website or application; closure and comments to that effect should make that clear to them.

Comment: Well then, how large is "too large"? Here, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114987/are-we-allowed-to-pass-strings-to-bison-functions - a full file of ~250 lines. Not over the limit but still quite a wall of code - definitely not an MCVE.

Comment: Two things:  first, that question [has some history to it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40114987/revisions); it didn't always have that giant wall of code and it was indeed justifiable to close it because there was insufficient information to help answer the question.  Now, it's been edited, and the hope here is that someone with experience in the language will evaluate the question and see if it should be reopened.  Second, there's no hard-and-fast limit to the amount of code, but it should "feel" like it's about the right length.

Comment: Well, I _feel_ it's not an MCVE and thus it's the OP's job to reduce it to something without irrelevant bits before they ask us to look at it. Do I feel right?

Comment: The root problem here is if/when they do, they will likely identify the issue in the process - so there won't be a question no more. That's basically why I am asking if these questions are off topic.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev:  I can't say; I don't really understand the language in the question.  I don't know if there's *just* enough to answer the question, so I can't comment on it reasonably.