# Can I heavily edit my question if I answer it myself?

Tags: discussion, edits

About a month ago, I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575435/mediawiki-login-cancelled-to-prevent-session-hijacking), which, after a few weeks, I ended up solving on my own. At the time of posting the question, I was unsure what information was important, so I included more than was necessary. Now that I've answered my own question though, I've realized most of the information in my question is irrelevant. A future user with the same issue might not even recognize that my problem was the same as theirs.

Now, I know typically an answered question shouldn't be edited much, as it runs a risk of invalidated something the answerer said, either at the expense of the answerer (for now having written a wrong answer) or future users (for now seeing an accepted but incorrect answer). Being the answerer though, I don't mind risking something at my own expense, and I also know what information led me to my answer, so I think I can improve the question for future users.

My two reservations are A) I don't know if this is ok, and B) there's one other answer on the question which is very helpful for similar issues, but isn't for my particular case (he addresses a session token changing, while it turns out mine was disappearing). My change would wipe out pretty much everything his answer references, making it mostly useless, but the fact that it wasn't relevant for my exact question makes me think that might be ok.

I get that reservation B makes this kind of question-specific, but if there's a general consensus on whether heavily editing self-answered questions is ok, I'd much prefer that instead of adding another slightly different meta question every time this comes up.

Comment: Sure make it as improved as necessary. Keep in mind your question should be useful for future research about the same problem.

Comment: As long as you don't invalidate anyone's answer go for it.

Comment: Perhaps this is more a case of *cleaning* the initial question rather than wholesale question slaughter. Organising the information that you provide is definitely a step forward, along with removing the so called red herrings. Moving information into different logically associated paragraphs helps with flow.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The main, overriding rule/goal of SE Q&As is:

- **The Q&A should be useful for future readers**

All other rules - one concern per question, self-contained, reasonable scope, no drastic topic/focus changes etc - are corollaries.

Deleting irrelevant info only helps that goal, so that's completely okay. Do make sure that it really is irrelevant though.

Comment: This seems to elude many, many users on SO. BTW, not only the OP can do this, other users can do this too.

Comment: Except in this case, deleting the information invalidates the other answers.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I think the issue here it is *further* invalidates an almost-valid answer, but the more I think about it, the less that seems like an issue. Like I said in the comments to dbenham's answer, if a user did end up getting helped by the other answer it would be by luck, since the question/accepted answer address a separate issue.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: you can leave a note at the bottom or top of your question, pointing out that a previous version has X Y and Z, see that for what some of the answers are talking about.  People that are curious can look and solve the mystery of the weird answers; people that are helped by the updated question and answer won't have to wade through confusion.

Comment: @LordFarquaad Note that I didn't include the "Do make sure that it really is irrelevant though." sentence just for show. If a log is normally relevant (just happened to not be in this case in the end, after you investigated it), omitting it would rather make the info incomplete. If there's a prominent clue but it's a red herring, it may be worth noting this and how you guessed that rather than just pretend it never happened so that others do not fall into the same trap (maybe for their case, if won't be a red herring). See which way would result in a better exposition.

Comment: @LordFarquaad And, for your own sake, _do not overthink it._ Too much info ([to a reasonable extent, of course](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339254/if-my-question-is-long-because-of-relevant-but-not-critical-details-that-can-b)) is better than insufficient info. If you're unsure if it brings more harm or good, leave it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453455/pythoncom-cocreateinstance-cant-create-izoneidentifier-the-interface-is-missin where the majority of the info proved to be irrelevant but I left it 'cuz that's what the problem looked like when I encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your current question to focus it. Then, ask a new question tailored to the other answer. Comment on the other answer (perhaps in advance) to let the other answerer know the situation, encouraging them to copy their answer to the new question and delete it from the old question.

I think this maximizes usefulness to future readers by providing answers to both questions in a way that is straightforward and discoverable.

Answer (score -9):

You could divide your question into two parts - At the top, restrict yourself to information that is pertinent to the actual problem. Then add a header for the second part, saying something like "Additional unreleated info that was included prior to my full understanding of the issue". And then include the other information, especially that which led to other answers.

Comment: I would discourage including "discussion history" into posts - Q&A format isn't fit for that. Such posts are hard to read for future visitors because anything not directly relevant to the end result is effectively noise. It's useful while the discussion is in progress but not after that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - I fail to see how information in the original question that led to a good answer is noise. I'm really shocked that so many people think my proposal is a bad one (+6, -7 at the time of this comment)

Comment: @dbenham I think I'm leaning towards ivan's side here. I do agree that the other user's answer is good advice for a changing session token, but my question ended up not being about that. In fact, me including my session tokens ended up being a red herring, which is what prompted the other answer in the first place. If anything, the existence of a "good but not quite in this scenario" answer backs up the idea that I should take out the irrelevant info, since it clearly can lead people down a wrong (but reasonable) track.

Comment: @dbenham If a future user ends up getting help from the other answer, it would be because they happened to stumble across a question which coincidentally had an answer for a separate issue, and I think it's fairly against SO's nature to plan for that case.