# Add the information that is required in a question into "How to ask"

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Earlier, in the [question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype), the SO team included a typical template of a question.

Let's add similar pointers to the [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) help article, so that novices can see what information they are required to provide for us to be able to answer, and so that we can quickly refer to it for a question that is lacking the required information, and save everyone the frustration of having to explain what is missing for the 1000th time and getting the missing bits.

Then, instead of "[condescending or snarky responses](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/06/21/rolling-out-the-welcome-wagon-june-update/)" about someone failing to do the debugging, constructing an MCVE or gooling their error message for the 2000th time, one could simply say "see [ask]", where everything that they may be missing would be clearly outlined.

E.g. something like this (not proposing this specific wording, only showing the key points to cover):

> In a question, you need to provide *all* the information that is
>   required to give a definitive answer. Besides, any problem must be
>   described in a way that is useful for future readers that have the
>   same problem.
>
> Unless you know what you're doing, stick to the following template.
>   Describe:
>
> - What task you're solving. Give reference links for any non-mainstream libraries and algorithms if they are directly relevant
>     to the problem.
> - An example of code, commands and sample data to reproduce the problem, and their output that demonstrates the problem. [Any code
>     must be cleaned up from any details not required to reproduce the
>     problem, and any data must be minimal ("A Minimal, Complete and
>     Verifiable example")](/help/mcve). if a large array of data is
>     required for the problem to show up, include a short code to generate
>     a sample of random data of a necessary length.
>
>   - It's *your job* to construct this "isolated" example *before* asking a question. [Asking to localize the problem for you is off
>       topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336507/questions-about-localizing-a-problem).
> - The details of your environment that are required for another person to run your code sample and reproduce the error.
>
>   - It's because of this step that you're required to construct a minimal example: if too many steps are required from a clean
>       installation, you won't be able to accurately describe them here.
> - What measures you tried, unsuccessfully, to solve the problem (which is also *your job to do, before asking here*): [what debugging the
>     code showed](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/), [what essential reading on the topic and online
>     resources and topics your looked through](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), what alternative
>     approaches you tried and/or considered and what they resulted in (with
>     an MCVE, too, if descriptino alone is not sufficient to understand the
>     reason for failure).

Maybe a style guide, too (elaborating on other style topics should be in another Q&A; here, I only mention what is a part of the question's template):

> Avoid any disclaimers like "thanks in advance" etc. At SO, and in online communities in general, you rather show respect by respecting others' time -- by giving, clear, concise and sufficient information that doesn't require others to waste their time squeezing the missing bits from you.

I.e. **"How to Ask" should be a step-by-step guide for writing a question** rather than a formless compilation of vague general advice. **But for now, I'm only proposing to integrate this specific information** so as not to scare off the hesitating crowd with radical changes leading God-knows-where.

Comment: @Makoto [forgetting that "How to ask" even exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370090/add-the-information-that-is-required-in-a-question-into-how-to-ask/370091#comment603437_370091) ([pic for <10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2k2S.png)) is quite telling about how (ir)relevant is it for practical use now TBH.

Comment: *"Asking to localize the problem for you is off topic."* That. Very much that.